# How to add two strings that are numbers?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i am looping through some nodes and getting the charge and adding them together. the charge is of type string though.

first time it loops string charge = "309",

second time it loop string charge = "38";

```
 `Looping through list of nodes
 {
   saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage += totalSvcNode.InnerText;
 }
`
```

I would have expected that I could add them together, but they are being concatenated instead like this:

```
`charge + charge = '30938'`
```

How can I force these strings to be treated as numbers? and get output like this at the end of the loop

```
`charge + charge = '347'`
```

Comment: [`int.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: I tend to prefer the TryParse() methods, as they don't raise exceptions.  There are a number of ways to convert strings to numbers, though.

Comment: use google to do a `MSDN search on int.Parse()` Method show a little bit more effort on your end. `Google` is your friend

Comment: If you can delete this message ;) maybe you get the peer pressure badge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people allready answered this maybe another solution
So you don't get errors

```
    private static int AddTwoStrings(string one, string two) 
    {
        int iOne = 0;
        int iTwo = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(one, out iOne);
        Int32.TryParse(two, out iTwo);
        return iOne + iTwo;
    }
```

Or if you want a string result.

```
private static String AddTwoStrings(string one, string two) 
{
    int iOne = 0;
    int iTwo = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(one, out iOne);
    Int32.TryParse(two, out iTwo);
    return (iOne + iTwo).ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Alexei Levenkov stated you could/should handle exceptions.
Maybe something like this will help you during development

```
    private static int AddTwoStrings(string one, string two) 
    {
        int iOne = 0;
        int iTwo = 0;
        bool successParseOne = Int32.TryParse(one, out iOne);
        bool successParseTwo = Int32.TryParse(two, out iTwo);
        if (!successParseOne) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("one");
        }
        else if(!successParseTwo)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("two");
        }

        return (iOne + iTwo);
    }
```

So when you have a wrong number you will be notified if you use try/catch

Comment: Although it is not the best question, I think this is a good answer.

Comment: I guess this one will be closed ;)

Comment: Generally it is bad idea to ignore results of `TryParse`... On other hand for Javascript / stringly typed code errors don't matter.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay good point. I added a sort of error handling. I firstly assumed that he then wanted to receive a valid number but giving him the choice is maybe a better soluton

Comment: @Bongo, your second chunk of code should have `string` as the return type.

Comment: @DangerZone oh right thanks i'll fix this

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the numbers from the strings:

```
string number1 = "309";
string number2 = "38";

int result = int.Parse(number1) + int.Parse(number2);
```

Then you can set the text equal to that string representation:

```
string addResult = result.ToString();
```

*Note: `Int32.Parse()` will throw an exception if the format isn't correct.  Consider using `Int32.TryParse()` for a bool way to capture an impossible parsing.*

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert your strings to integer, add them and convert the result back to string:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (string strNumber in strNumberCollection)
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(strNumber, out number))
        sum += number;
}

string total = sum.ToString();
```