# Convert a string to int and then pass that value to a string

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

Is there a simpler way to add 3 strings together by parsing it as integers and then pass the resulting value to a string?

For example:

```
public string SumVal;
public string val_1;
public string val_2;
public string val_3;

void Start()
{
    SumVal = int.Parse(val_1) + int.Parse(val_2) + int.Parse(val_3);
}
```

Comment: this will give compilation error

Comment: based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711326/how-to-add-two-strings-that-are-numbers there is no better way

Comment: String interpolation would go best I think

Comment: @NaveedYousaf define "best" (and also OP define "simplier")  ... in readability? In maintainability? In being fail-safe? In performance/efficiency? ... ;)

Comment: @derHugo I guess performing alot of operations such as converting strings to ints and then back to string, it takes alot of processing power if the values are in 100. So I was looking for a simpler way without converting each string to int.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take care of the case if the string is not convertible to int also otherwise it will give an exception (System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.').

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
bool b = int.TryParse(val_1, out x);
int.TryParse(val_2, out y);
int.TryParse(val_3, out z);

SumVal = (x + y + z).ToString();
```

You can check for the return `bool` variable if it's false` then you can handle the case accordingly

Comment: Where are you taking care of it? ;-)

Comment: because the default value of int is 0 so it will give you 0, but again that wont be a perfect solution

Comment: So maybe you should at least throw a warning `if(!int.TryParse(val_2, out var y) { Debug.LogWarning($"Could not parse Y with input \"{val_2}\""); }`

Comment: ...or better build it robust and clean which includes educating OP how to do so ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation

```
SumVal = $"{int.Parse(val_1)+int.Parse(val_2)+int.Parse(val_3)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah it did not come to me that I can add all the three values inside a bracket and pass it to ToString(). But looks like it cannot be more simpler than this.

```
SumVal = (int.Parse(val_1) + int.Parse(val_2) + int.Parse(val_3)).ToString();
```

Comment: This will only work if your val_1, val_2 and val_3 always contain integer values. If one of them is not an integer you get a System.FormatException.